Estoy intentando hacer un treeview scrolleable y añadirle entradas para leerlas como lo hago
Estoy intentando hacer un treeview que tenga de titulos Nombre, Desayuno, Almuerzo, y Cena,  en la columna de Nombre ya logre rellenar los datos tomando los datos de una tupla que escanee usando openpyxl, pero en las otras 3 columnas quiero poner entradas para que digite la cantidad que consume de ese alimento en la respectiva zona horaria sin embargo buscnaod ayuda en chat GPT encontre un código que es el siguiente  que funciona pero querer generalizarlo (Sin usar clases ya que no las domino aun)y  no se adapta a mi código general
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class SimpleTreeviewWithEntries(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Treeview con Entradas Simplificado")
        self.geometry("500x200")

        # Crear Treeview
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=("Nombre", "Desayuno", "Almuerzo", "Cena"), show="headings", height=5)
        self.tree.heading("Nombre", text="Nombre")
        self.tree.heading("Desayuno", text="Desayuno")
        self.tree.heading("Almuerzo", text="Almuerzo")
        self.tree.heading("Cena", text="Cena")
        
        self.tree.column("Nombre", width=150, anchor="center")
        self.tree.column("Desayuno", width=100, anchor="center")
        self.tree.column("Almuerzo", width=100, anchor="center")
        self.tree.column("Cena", width=100, anchor="center")
        
        self.tree.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Insertar filas con alimentos
        alimentos = [("Papa", "", "", ""), ("Queso", "", "", "")]
        for alimento in alimentos:
            self.tree.insert("", "end", values=alimento)

        # Actualizar la interfaz gráfica para asegurarse de que todo está renderizado
        self.update_idletasks()

        # Crear entradas para las celdas de Desayuno, Almuerzo y Cena
        self.entries = {}  # Diccionario para almacenar las entradas
        self.create_entries()

    def create_entries(self):
        # Recorrer cada fila
        for item in self.tree.get_children():
            for col_index in range(1, 4):  # Omitir la primera columna ("Nombre")
                bbox = self.tree.bbox(item, column=col_index)
                if bbox:
                    x, y, width, height = bbox
                    # Crear Entry
                    entry = tk.Entry(self)
                    entry.place(x=x + self.tree.winfo_x() + 1,  # Ajuste en x
                                y=y + self.tree.winfo_y() + 1,  # Ajuste en y
                                width=width, height=height)
                    # Almacenar la referencia del Entry en el diccionario
                    col_name = self.tree["columns"][col_index]
                    self.entries[(item, col_name)] = entry

    def get_entry_values(self):
        # Método para obtener los valores de todas las entradas
        data = {}
        for (item, col_name), entry in self.entries.items():
            nombre = self.tree.item(item, "values")[0]
            value = entry.get()
            data.setdefault(nombre, {})[col_name] = value
        return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SimpleTreeviewWithEntries()
    app.mainloop()

Aqui las funciones originales de mi código en el pedazo del dataframe que esta en la parte superior izquierda ya que tengo 4 componentes en un grid.


Horacomida = ["Desayuno", "Almuerzo", "Cena", "Total"] 
Tiponut = ["Nombre","Calorias (kcal)", "Grasas (g)", "Proteinas (g)", "Carbohidratos (g)","Azucares (g)" ,"Colesterol (mg)" ]
entries = {} # Diccioniario para tomar valores

# Frame mayor
frame = ttk.Frame(root) 
frame.pack()

 # SUP IZQ El frame para entrada del usuario

dietaframe = ttk.Labelframe(frame, text="Alimentación")
dietaframe.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

# Crear un Canvas para dibujar los Entry widgets sobre el Treeview

def Crearentradas():
    # Recorrer cada fila
    for item in treedieta.get_children():
        for col_index in range(1, 4):  # Omitir la primera columna ("Nombre")
            bbox = treedieta.bbox(item, column=col_index)
            if bbox:
                x, y, width, height = bbox
                # Crear Entry
                entry = tk.Entry(dietaframe)
                entry.place(x=x + treedieta.winfo_x() + 1,  # Ajuste en x
                            y=y + treedieta.winfo_y() + 1,  # Ajuste en y
                            width=width, height=height)
                # Almacenar la referencia del Entry en el diccionario
                col_name = treedieta["columns"][col_index]
                entries[(item, col_name)] = entry


def get_entry_values():
    # Método para obtener los valores de todas las entradas
    data = {}
    for (item, col_name), entry in treedieta.items():
        nombre = treedieta.item(item, "values")[0]
        value = entry.get()
        data.setdefault(nombre, {})[col_name] = value
    return data

def Llenarentrada():
    #Necesito el excel de nuevo para imprimir los nombres (Sólo para eso)
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(BDali)
    sheet = workbook.active
    list_values = list(sheet.values)

    # Configurar los encabezados
    for Tipocomida in Titulosdieta:
        treedieta.heading(Tipocomida, text=Tipocomida)

    # Leer los valores de la hoja de Excel
    
    # Iterar sobre las filas, ya que que la primera fila osea la priemra tuplca es de encabezados 
    for fila in list_values[1:]:  # Ajusta el rango según la cantidad de filas que quieras procesar
        nombre = fila[0]  # Dado que el nombre esta en el indice 0
        print(nombre)
        treedieta.insert("", tk.END, values=(nombre,)) #Añade los nombres  ## CUIDADO CON LA COMA  dela TUPLA Para que añada bien los nombres

    treedieta.update_idletasks() # Acutaliza la interfaz
    Crearentradas() # Crea las entradas

#############################################################################################################
Titulosdieta = ["Nombre", "Desayuno", "Almuerzo", "Cena"]
scrolldieta = ttk.Scrollbar(dietaframe)   # Para permitir scrollear necesitamos el scroll
scrolldieta.pack(side="right", fill="y") # Para que tome todo el espacio y se quede en la derecha verticalmente usamos el fill y 

treedieta = ttk.Treeview(dietaframe, show="headings", yscrollcommand=scrolldieta.set ,columns=Titulosdieta, height=8) # Sol muestra las aplicaciones con ehadings
for Tipocomida in Titulosdieta:
        treedieta.heading(Tipocomida, text=Tipocomida)
treedieta.column("Nombre", width=200)
treedieta.column("Desayuno", width=100)
treedieta.column("Almuerzo", width=100)
treedieta.column("Cena", width=100)


treedieta.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

scrolldieta.config(command=treedieta.yview) # EL tree view se meuve a lo largo del eje y 

Llenarentrada() # Para llenar los nombres y crear las entradas

enviardieta = ttk.Button(dietaframe, text="Enviar Dieta", )  
enviardieta.pack()

Pero el código no inserta las entradas y no encuentro el por qué. Agradecería cualquier recomendación si pueden ver el error, u otros aspectos a mejorar.
